# IntelliJ: Symbol 'type org.scalatest.compatible.Assertion' is missing from the classpath

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Writing scala tests, I am encountering an error:

```
Symbol 'type org.scalatest.compatible.Assertion' is missing from the classpath.
This symbol is required by 'type org.scalatest.Assertion'.
Make sure that type Assertion is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
A full rebuild may help if 'package.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.scalatest.compatible.
```

My build.sbt is very simple:

```
import sbt.Keys.libraryDependencies

ThisBuild / scalaVersion     := "2.13.2"
ThisBuild / version          := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / organization     := "com.example"
ThisBuild / organizationName := "example"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "myproj",
    libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.2.9",
    libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.9" % "test",
    libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest-funsuite" % "3.2.9" % "test",
    libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.1.2",
    )
```

This problem only occurs when I build my project within IntelliJ. Using sbt itself it compiles well.

```
sbt version in this project: 1.3.10
sbt script version: 1.3.6
```

Any idea of how to fix it in IntelliJ?

Comment: Obvious advice but worth mentioning - did you try `File -> Invalidate Caches`?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the problems related to IntelliJ being broken I resolve by doing so:

1. `sbt clean compile` in terminal on root folder
2. `View -> Tool Windows -> sbt` and within tab `Reload SBT project` (right click on project)